Header size different from dev to release with Expo React native android app
I'm building an android App using React native and Expo tools.
I've set a custom header component using
{    
    header: (props) => <CustomHeader {...props} />
}

In a tabScreen options and also in Stack screen option. (issue occurs on both)
The header size is set in CustomHeaders root view "style" prop : style={height:82, paddingTop: 24}   (I leave space for system's status bar)
The design is great in dev mode (Expo development build)
but as soon as I build my app for release (using gradle bundleRelease to get the aab bundle for google play) the app gets a weird space at the top. ( as you can see on the screen shot below, I've let space for the system status bar, but a padding is added IN RELEASE BUILD ONLY)

In dev mode, the light blue above the header doesn't exist and the status bar is transparent above the header dark blue color.
I've try to play with navigationOptions.headerForceInset without success (as I'm overriding default header maybe this rule won't apply ?)
I've seen this from here.
As I'm using a TabBarNavigator and a StackView I guess I don't have to add a SafeAreaView ?
I think it's weird this issue occur only on Release build.  Does anyone understand this ?
thank you for your help.
More info on libraries versions:
"expo": "~50.0.15",
"react-native": "0.73.6",
"react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.8",
"react-native-pager-view": "6.2.3",
"react-native-paper": "^4.7.2",
"react-native-reanimated": "~3.6.2",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
"react-native-screens": "~3.29.0",
"react-native-tab-view": "^3.0.0",
"react-native-webview": "13.8.6",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "6.3.1",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.2",
"@react-navigation/elements": "1.3.3",
"@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "6.2.1",
"@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "6.2.1",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16",

